# Qt - Writing integer data into JSON

Tags: c++, json, qt

I am using Qt (5.5) and I want to exchange data in JSON format in a client-server application.

So the format is constant:

```
{
    "ball":
    {
        "posx": 12,
        "posy": 35
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to define a ByteArray or string like so:

`QByteArray data = "{\"ball\":{\"posx\":%s,\"posy\":%s}}"`

and then just write whatever the values for that into the string.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QtJson` is baked into Qt 5.  It is easy to use, and gets it all ready for you pretty easily.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonDocument>

void saveToJson(QJsonObject & json);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QJsonObject jsonObject;

    saveToJson(jsonObject);

    QJsonDocument jsonDoc(jsonObject);

    qDebug() << "Example of QJsonDocument::toJson() >>>";
    qDebug() << jsonDoc.toJson();
    qDebug() << "<<<";

    return a.exec();
}

void saveToJson(QJsonObject & json)
{
    QJsonObject ball;
    ball["posx"] = 12;
    ball["posy"] = 35;

    json["ball"] = ball;
}
```

output

```
Example of QJsonDocument::toJson() >>>
"{
    "ball": {
        "posx": 12,
        "posy": 35
    }
}
"
<<<
```

Note: `qDebug()` wraps `QString` objects in quotes when printing. To get rid of that, pass your `QString` into `qPrintable()`.  And it puts `endl` in for you at the end of each line.

For a more complex example see the official:

JSON Save Game Example

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-json-savegame-example.html

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

And here are more examples of string manipulations, but for readability and maintainability, please use the `QJson` classes.

```
QString str;
str = QString("{\"ball\":{\"posx\":%1,\"posy\":%2}}").arg(12).arg(35);
qDebug() << qPrintable(str);

QByteArray ba = str.toLocal8Bit();

qDebug() << ba;

QString str2;

str2 = "{\"ball\":{\"posx\":"
        + QString::number(12)
        + ",\"posy\":"
        + QString::number(35)
        + "}}";
qDebug() << qPrintable(str2);
```

output

```
{"ball":{"posx":12,"posy":35}}
"{"ball":{"posx":12,"posy":35}}"
{"ball":{"posx":12,"posy":35}}
```

Note again that the quotes are added by `qDebug()` when printing a `QByteArray` object.

Hope that helps.